# How get determined buttons from class

Tags: c#

this is not long story!! just it seems to be long ;)

in my app I have `user access`, it means access to a button relate to its user access scope.

in winform layer: I have a form, it shows all of the determined buttons' name in partitioned checkedListboxes. I dont want fill the form manually. I want create checkedListboxes by code. to get their items'text, I have below planing:

**clssMenu_Item:** I can save `name` and `text` property of one button in this class.

```
public class clssMenu_Item
{
    public string name;
    public string text;
}
```

**clssMenu_List:** it give me 2D generic `List<clssMenu_Item>`. all of the buttons in one form will be in a object of this class.

```
public class clssMenu_List
{
    public clssMenu_List ()
    {
           // I dont know how fill private variables     
    }
    #region private variables
        private List<clssMenu_Item> _main ; // buttons in main form
        private List<clssMenu_Item> _accountancy; //buttons in accountancy form
        private List<clssMenu_Item> _management; //buttons in management form
    #endregion 
    #region public properties

        public List<clssMenu_Item> main
        { get { return _main; } }

        public List<clssMenu_Item> accountancy
        { get { return _accountancy; } }

        public List<clssMenu_Item> management
        { get { return _management; } }

    #endregion
}
```

the buttons in each forms have a common character in their `Name property`. For example all of the determined buttons in Main form are started with ''Mbtn'', so there isn't any same buttons' Name between forms. 
now I dont know how fill private variables in `clssMenu_List`. then I could use it in my facade layer.

thanks for your attention my friend!! please help me to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a separated helper class that extracts all buttons from a form.

```
public static class FormHelper
{
    public static Button[] GetButtonsFromForm(Form form)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I would create properties instead of fields:

```
public class clssMenu_Item
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Text {get;set;}
}
```

A method to create menu_items:

```
public IEnumerable<clssMenu_Item> GetMenuItemsFromForm(Form form)
{
   // convert the buttons to menu_items
   return from button in FormHelper.GetButtonsFromForm(form);
          select new clssMenu_Item { Name = button.Name, Text = button.Text };
}
```

Next I would add all buttons to the right list.

```
public void Fill()
{
    clssMenu_List lst = new clssMenu_List();

    clssMenu_List.main.AddRange(GetMenuItemsFromForm(mainForm));
    clssMenu_List.accountancy.AddRange(GetMenuItemsFromForm(accountancyForm));
    clssMenu_List.management.AddRange(GetMenuItemsFromForm(managementForm));

}
```

Don't forget to create the list in you class:

```
    private List<clssMenu_Item> _main = new List<classMenu_Item>(); // buttons in main form
    private List<clssMenu_Item> _accountancy = new List<classMenu_Item>(); //buttons in accountancy form
    private List<clssMenu_Item> _management = new List<classMenu_Item>(); //buttons in management form
```

Personally:

I would store them in a dictionary because you can access them by name. And I would not create properties of List-types. I'd rather create Add/Remove methods.

Comment: I didnt work with dictionary already. just need replace all `List` types to `dictionary` ?

Comment: I think you first should try this, then you could read here about dictionaries. http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary. Did my answer help?

Comment: Thank u. but I should write `Fill` method for each form. like: `fillMainForm(Form frm)`

Comment: The fill method i wrote, handles the mainForm, accountancyForm, managementForm.